# UTF8 encoding problem

Tags: java, encoding

I am working with a html file.. I used html cleaner to clean the html file then the format is changed (All 'e's replaced by +®)... how can i correct that in java

Comment: That's weird, because even if you compose those two ASCII chars `+®` as a single Unicode char (`0x2BAE`) it's an unassigned Unicode codepoint.  And `e` is the same in ASCII and UTF8.  Any idea of what encoding it may have tried to convert from/to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post some code on what you are doing.  Here is an answer I got to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151868/reading-a-line-from-a-text-file-using-filereader-using-system-out-println-seems)

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("filename");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-16"));
```